# ModelState.Isvalid, why does it validate relatetd Tabels?

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, entities

This is the properties to validate. (Code from my cshtml.cs (Razor))

```
    [BindProperty]
    public TMedProductStorageLocation TMedProductStorageLocation { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public IList<TStorageLocation> TStorageLocations { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int SelectedStorageLocationId { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public TMedProduct SelectedProduct { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public int RelocateAmount { get; set; }
```

These are the properties I want to Validate. But It also Validates:

```
  public class TSubstanceGroup
{

    public TSubstanceGroup()

    {
        TMedProducts = new HashSet<TMedProduct>();

    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie eine Bezeichnung ein.")]

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TMedProduct> TMedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

because this is a related table to TMedProduct.
How can I avoid validation for related tables?

Comment: Could you please share your razor pages frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is your razor pages design,but you need to know that ModelState will validate all the models you define in razor pages backend not due to you have relationship between models:

```
public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public TSubstanceGroup TSubstanceGroup { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public TMedProduct SelectedProduct { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public TMedProductStorageLocation TMedProductStorageLocation { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public IList<TStorageLocation> TStorageLocations { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int SelectedStorageLocationId { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int RelocateAmount { get; set; }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
       //...
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        //..
    }
    
}
```

To avoid validation for related tables,you could remove the validation with the key:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    ModelState.Remove("KeyName");
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //...
    }
    return Page();
}
```

For how to know the key name,you could check in the ModelState:
[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for that answer!! Now I know why Modelstate was Invalid and how I can avoid it.